# Unmarshal array of different types

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I have a string of a valid JSON that needs to be Unmarshaled, but the array is hard to fit in a structure to Unmarshal and I can't figure out how to do it. It looks a bit like this:

```
[
    [ "name", "contains", "test" ],
    "and",
    [ "group", "=", "123" ],
    "and",
    [
        [
            "date", ">=", "2020-06-30T23:00:00Z"
        ],
        "and",
        [
            "date", "<", "2020-07-31T23:00:00Z"
        ]
    ]
]
```

It can have deeper arrays as well.

What I tried so far is

```
f := r.URL.Query().Get("filter")
var dat []map[string]interface{}
// Also failed with: dat := make([]map[string]interface{}, 100)

if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(f), &dat); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

And the error is always the same `panic: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]interface {}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your json data is complex and you can not define it to go struct or any type, often I try just `interface{}`.

In your case, the contents of the array from your json data, are not key-value structured. And hence you can not unmarshal it to an array of `map[string]interface{}`. So, try out this one.

```golang
var jsonStr = `
[
    [ "name", "contains", "test" ],
    "and",
    [ "group", "=", "123" ],
    "and",
    [
        [
            "date", ">=", "2020-06-30T23:00:00Z"
        ],
        "and",
        [
            "date", "<", "2020-07-31T23:00:00Z"
        ]
    ]
]
`

func main() {
    var data interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &data); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/fC8XVvHutzm

I often use https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to convert json to go struct.